# Making some kind of see-through glass image in css/html/js

Tags: javascript, html, css

When viewing this website: http://myankle.co.uk/faq/

Whenever you scroll down or up, the image of the ankle changes.  I know that you can make a div opaque and put an image behind it, but how is this effect being done? The image seems to move with the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achieved by setting a background as `background-attachment: fixed`. The effect is a basic implementation of parallax.

A good article to get you started is http://davidwalsh.name/parallax

An example class to apply this would be:

```
.parallax {
  background-image: url('http://demoimage.com/image.jpg');
  background-color: none !important;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed; // For mobile this should be scroll to fix bugs with ios
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You add a background-image to body that is position: fixed; and then make html content on top of it transparent, so you can see the background-image. It's not moving with the page, that is an illusion.

Answer (score 1):

That element uses a [`background-attachment` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) to fix the image relative to the screen:

> If a background-image is specified, the `background-attachment` CSS property determines whether that image's position is fixed within the viewport, or scrolls along with its containing block.

```css
elem {
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/oqsaoysy/).